# Pi4 stopped booting with kernel panic

Tags: boot-issues

As you can see from the screenshot, it stops after just 2 seconds, don't know even where to start:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekTfG.jpg

It had an uptime of a few months, has a 64GB card with a 32GB data partition, the card is pretty fresh (less than one year).

I put the card into an Ubuntu system, was able to scan the system partition and there were no bad sectors or anything else abnormal. Could even mount the partition and make a full backup.

I suspect that the boot partition or boot files are corrupted (there are a lot of files in lost&found).

I could set it up again but would be quite time-consuming as I have a ton of services. Not sure if I should try to make a new setup on a HDD or SSD, or if a USB stick is more reliable.

Comment: Have you seen the lines teilling you `CPU 0 stopping` and `CPU 2 stopping`? There must have been a seriuos issue **before** these lines. You can try with a fresh SD card and then tell us whether the problem persists.

Comment: Your 5.4 kernel is way out of date. Current kernel is 5.10.17. Current beta kernel is 5.10.25. Try building a new SDCard with a fresh copy of RaspiOS.

Comment: "I could set it up again but would be quite time-consuming" - just restore from your backup.

Comment: @Milliways I have a file backup as well as separate backups for more involved service (home assistant) but essentially it would mean just copying the old files over a freshly installed system. Not sure if that's the best approach for this. I would still need to set up all the packages (which ones?) and make sure the symlinks are updated. Not sure if there is any way to avoid this.

Comment: you have a lost&found folder in the boot partition? how did you do that? What you could do is image a new sd card, then simply copy the boot partition across to the old card

Comment: SD cards only have a limited number of writes and the most cost effect cards normally have fewer writes.    USB flash storage suffered from the same issues..

IMHO USB 3.0 SATA adapter and a USAP compliant SATA SSD is the best storage option at this point for RPI4.0. 

Another factor is power supply I recently had a RPI4 repeatably lose its networking and on occasion hang..

Turns out that the cheap Usb adaptor I was using for 2 months was spiking the PI..

Fortunately switching out the duff supply with a new one solved the issues..

Comment: @Neppomuk @ Dougie I am copying now the data from the attached HDD to a spare one and will try a fresh install on the attached HDD. I'm pretty sure the Pi is fine since it runs headless, at 20% usage and has a heatsink and fan.. @ Jaromanda most of the L&F files have an older timestamp as a result of an older fsck.